# I want to use a anonymous function inside an object

Tags: javascript, oop, function, settimeout, infinite-loop

I have this code for a newsfeed that I want to use.

I want it to look kind of like this:

```
function News(){

    //Load new comments every 5 sec
    setTimeout((function(){
        console.log(this); //Returns Object #News
        this.loadNewsFeed();
    }).call(this),5000);

    this.loadNewsFeed = function(){
        // Implementation here
    }
}
```

The problem here is that it says the Object News doesn't have an method called `loadNewsFeed`!

I've already got it to work if I put the anonymous function **outside** the object News.

Like this:

```
var news = new News();
//Load new comments every 5 sec
(function loopNews(){
    news.loadNewsFeed();
    setTimeout(loopNews,5000);
})();
```

So how can I do this **inside** the object `News`?

Comment: Replace `.call` with `.bind`

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem) goes into some deatil about how to deal with the 'this' problem.

Comment: But you must be aware of the required browser support of `bind` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
function News()
{
    var self = this;

    this.loadNewsFeed = function(){
        // Implementation here
    };

    //Load new comments every 5 sec
    setInterval(function handler() // setInterval for endless calls
    {
        console.log(self); //Returns Object #News
        self.loadNewsFeed();
        return handler;
    }(), 5000);
}
```

Explanation:
`call(this)` invokes the handler **directly** - and returns `undefined` to `setInterval` which means that it's executed immediately but **no handler is set**.
The handler-function executes in global context so `this` is the `window`-object. The local variable `self` **"injects"** the current (and desired) `this` - as `self`.

Edit 2:
Now executes **immediately** ***and***  **registers** a handler.

Comment: This question was asked just yesterday - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771889/setinterval-with-self-executing-function

Comment: Hmm, after your update @Warappa it didn't work. Still says:

#Object<News> doesn't have an method called loadNewsFeed

Comment: Oh, too many edits ;) - just move the handler-definition before setInterval then it works!

Comment: Can you add a new answer?:o Because I don't really get it. :/

I want it to work like you wrote here:

Now executes *immediately and registers* a handler.

Comment: Hm... I just copied the code (and added `new News()`) and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/sfgVy/

Comment: I've learned my lesson. It was because I didn't declare the method BEFORE.

I thought it didn't matter in this case so.. I thought of it as a regular "constructor" thing..

Sorry to bother.